# JavaScript - Composite objects with object properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties, nested

I want to create a composite object (eg `device`) which would have other objects as a properties (eg `position`).
Is this possible to achieve in JavaScript by using constructors?

```
var pos = new position(23,10,15);
var dev = new device(01,"mobile",pos);

//device obj constructor   
function device(id, type, position) {
   this.id=id;
   this.type=type;
   this.position = {position.lat, position.lon, position.alt};
}

//position obj constructor
function position(lat,lon,alt) {
   this.lat=lat;
   this.lon=lon;
   this.alt=alt;
}
```

I'm getting error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Comment: Do you need to use the pseudo-classical approach? (In other words, do you need to use constructors?)

Comment: If its possible, I would prefer it that way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You are getting SyntaxError, because you have a syntax error. You can nest objects like this:

```
device = {
    id: 43,
    type: 34,
    position: { 
       lat: 2,
       lon: 4,
       alt: 343 
       }
    };
```

Your function should look like this if you want to assign the whole object to the variable:

```
function device(id, type, position) {
    this.id=id;
    this.type=type;
    this.position = position;
}
```

However if you want to assign just some of the variables of the object, you should do it like this:

```
function device(id, type, position) {
    this.id=id;
    this.type=type;
    this.position = {
        alt: position.alt,
        lon: position.lon,
        lat: position.alt
    };
}
```

Comment: The last approach was the one I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

replace this line

```
this.position = {position.lat, position.lon, position.alt};
```

with this

```
this.position = position
```

Comment: Don't forget the `;` at the end of the line.

Comment: javascript is forgiveness language : ). it will work without `;`
but i do end my js statements with semicolon

Comment: that is absolutely correct, however it is always better to put it in to make sure that the browser's JavaScript interpreter doesn't mess up.